# Connecting multiple wifi network

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, wifi, camera

I am really new to the pi world, I have a quick question. I am planning to build a small wifi surveillance system with Pi. So basically 4 wifi camera's streaming data. I am planning to use [this camera](https://www.amazon.ca/Portable-Wireless-Cameras-Security-Support/dp/B078YPF312/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1545440379&sr=8-3&keywords=wifi%20camera%20module) . I want to capture those 4 streams through Pi. Is it possible to connect multiple wifi cameras at same time with Pi3 ?.

Comment: You might struggle to capture those streams at all, never mind all at the same time. I believe those cheap cameras usually use proprietary protocols, send the data to China and let you view it with a proprietary app. If I'm wrong I'd be very interested to know how it can be done but I'd certainly try a single camera first.

Comment: Yeah I am going to try with one camera now..